# FFMPEG (WINDOWS) - Jerky Videos with vidstabdetect & vidstabtransform

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I require to stabilize multiple video clips and finally stitch all the clips, along with images into one final video. These "Scenes" consisting video clips as well as images also can have overlays like Texts and/or other Images.

Basically the code I have in place as of now does everything for me just fine, where all the video clips are first converted into frame images. It then reads all the frames, puts on the overlays, adds a fade transition in-between "Scenes".

Coming to the issue I am facing with stabilization, when I extract image frames out of the stabilized video clip and simply try to recreate video from those extracted image frames, it comes out with a weird jerk, almost like as if it is missing those stabilization calculations or something, not sure. It still looks a bit stabilized but with missing frames. I have checked duration and number of frames extracted, everything matches with the source, non-stabilized video.

Below is the command used to stabilize the video, result of which is a perfectly stabilized video.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.MOV -r 30 -vf vidstabdetect=result="transforms.trf" -f null NUL && ffmpeg -i 1.MOV -r 30 -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input="transforms.trf" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 2000k -f mp4 results.mp4
```

Below is the command I use for video to image:

```
ffmpeg -i results.mp4 -r 30 -qscale 1 -f image2 %d.jpg
```

Below is the command I use for image to video:

```
ffmpeg -i %d.jpg -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 2000k -f mp4 final.mp4
```

Any help or suggestions are welcomed and appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: In your image to video command, insert `-framerate 30` before the input and drop `-r 30`. Not sure if this solves your issue, but right now, ffmpeg is duplicating frames in that process.

Answer (score 0):

Stabilize the video first before converting them to images. Overlays and transitions will make your video look weird if you put them first before stabilization.